# How can I sum the numbers that are next to each other in the list and add that sum to the same list between the numbers that I sum?

Tags: java, list, sum

the list basically needs to go from (e.g.)
3 2 4
into a
3 5 2 6 4 , where 5 is a sum of 3 and 2 and 6 is a sum of 2 and 4.
numbers in a list are typed manually and a list can have an infinite size.

i think i have the base(if you can call it that), but I'm not sure how exactly I can sum the specific numbers in a list.
Here's what I got so far

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    
    int number;
    while (true){
      number = sc.nextInt();
      if(number==0)break;

      if(list.size()==0)
        list.add(number);
      else{

        // here's where I think the sum of numbers should be
        
        }
        list.add(i,number);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("result:");
    
        for (int n : list) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
    }

    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great first question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's that `i` you are using (I don't see it declared anywhere), but you don't need it.

Your loop can behave as follows:

```
int number;
while (true) {
  number = sc.nextInt();
  if(number==0)
      break;
  if(list.size() == 0) {
    list.add(number);
  } else{
    list.add(list.get(list.size()-1) + number);
    list.add(number);
  }
}
```

EDITED: I see that you want the sum of each pair of consecutive input numbers.

- If the list is empty, you just add the first number to the list.
- Otherwise, you add the sum of the last element added to the list and the new input number, and then you add the new input number.

Answer (score 0):

A more versatile approach would be to read the user's input and process the List separately, by splitting these responsibilities as [*the first principle of SOLID*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) suggests. That would allow to reuse the logic regardless of where the list is coming from.

## Create a new List

One of the ways to address this problem would be to generate a new List and populate it with elements and their sums from the original list while iterating over the original list.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static List<Integer> addSumBetweenElements(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptyList();
    
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int prev = list.get(0);
    result.add(prev);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int next = list.get(i);
        result.add(prev + next);
        result.add(next);
        prev = next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addSumBetweenElements(List.of(1, 2, 3)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 3]
```

## [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) - Modify the Original List

If your goal is to modify the original list, then you can make use of the functionality offered by the `ListIterator`.

The key thing to remember about Iterators is that they always occupy position ***in between the elements*** (*or before the very first, or right after the last element*). And the method [`ListIterator.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)) is being invoked, a new element gets inserted right after the *previous* (*which can be retrieved by `previous()` call*) and *next* element (*which can be obtained by invoking `next()`*).

```
public static List<Integer> addSumBetweenElements(List<Integer> list) {
    
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
    int prev = iterator.next();
    
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int next = iterator.next(); // advance one position forward to retrieve next element
        iterator.previous();        // move one step back (in between the previous and next elements)
        iterator.add(prev + next);  // insert a new element
        iterator.next();            // move one step forward (past the next element which has been processed)
        prev = next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addSumBetweenElements(new LinkedList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3))));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 3]
```